# Google App Engine: (Python) Datastore transactions and idempotence

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions

I'd like some help understanding transactions and indempotence.

> Note: If your app receives an exception when submitting a transaction,
>   it does not always mean that the transaction failed. You can receive
>   Timeout, TransactionFailedError, or InternalError exceptions in cases
>   where transactions have been committed and eventually will be applied
>   successfully. Whenever possible, make your Datastore transactions
>   idempotent so that if you repeat a transaction, the end result will be
>   the same.

I have a game where players receive an email when something special happens. There is a bug were players sometimes receive 2 (or more) emails. I believe its because I am processing the game rules inside a transaction, but sending of emails outside.

some pseudocode:

```
def game_update(orders_from_player):
  emails_to_send = db.run_in_transaction(process_player_orders, orders_from_player)
  for e in emails_to_send:
    send_email(e)
```

Is it true to say that, upon a transaction collision I should expect the list of emails to be sent out again?

Is the *whole request* repeated, or just the call to the transactional procedure.(in this case process_player_orders)

I'm confused.

Comment: Just the process_player_orders is retried. BTW, is it possible the result of process_player_orders contains the same e-mail address more than twice? Can you share the implementation of send_email()?

Comment: There is nothing special going on in send email, and to keep the question simple I neglected to mention that there are other internal messages going into the datastore twice as well.

It sure seems like the results of run_in_transaction are returned for each collision (for each time it is retried). Is that possible.

Comment: Is there a way I can simulate a collision in my local datastore to help debug this?