# Google App Engine: (Python 2.7) Do Transactions work when using the Memcache as well as the Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, memcached

A few days ago I posted a question about Transactions and Idempotence but didn't get much response.

[Google App Engine: (Python) Datastore transactions and idempotence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213106/google-app-engine-python-datastore-transactions-and-idempotence)

Today I realised that Transactions are a feature of the datastore but most of the time I am pulling my data from the Memcache, doing a bunch of work, then saving back to the memcache *and* datastore.

I only **get** data from the datastore if the data is missing in the memcache.

Will placing a function in a transaction prevent another request from pulling the same data from the memcache?

The examples typically look like this.

```
Begin Transaction
    Get Data from Datastore
    Do Work on data
    Put data back in Datastore
```

By my code looks like this much of the time

```
 Begin Transaction
    Get data from Memcache
    if not data:
        Get data from Datastore
    Do work on data
    Put to Memcache
    Put to Datastore
```

Will this work?

Is the transaction code smart enough to know prevent the entire block from running simultaneously, or is the lock only from the first datastore operation to the last datastore operation in the transaction function?

Is it possible that two requests are pulling the same data from the memcache, doing the work , but **not colliding when putting the data back in the datastore** causing the latter request to stomp on the changes of the first?

Comment: There is no transactional semantics for memcache.  You might want to look at memcache CAS https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/overview#Using_Compare_and_Set_in_Python   .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, database transactions do not span memcache.

Also - transactions do not lock. They use [optimistic concurrency control](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions#What_Can_Be_Done_In_a_Transaction), where under the hood every db entity has an update time which gets checked at transaction commit. If entities used in transaction (= entity group) has update time changed the transaction is dirty and exception is thrown - you need to repeat the whole transaction (this is for low-level, I believe python NDM does part of this work for you).

So to have transactions you need to load data from datastore at the beginning to get the "update times" needed for transaction to work. Your code would work, but would not be transactional.